# How do I select an element in a multidimensional array with another array in python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I would liketo know, if there is a way to use an array to select an element out of another array?

```
G=np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
            [[1,1,1],[1,8,1],[1,1,1]],
            [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]]])
```

Let's say, I wanted to select the '8', I would normally just do

```
In [101]: G[1,1,1]
Out[101]: 8
```

What I intend to do ist something like

```
In [102]: c=np.array([1,1,1])
In [103]: G[c]
Out[103]: 8
```

I know, that's to easy and it doesn't work. Ist there a way, that does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple)

```
G[tuple(c)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying for days, but I didn't find this.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you! Perhaps you can accept the answer if you found it helpful?